# How to partially mock a dependency abstract object in JMockit

Tags: java, jmockit

I have abstract class `D` which is a dependency of the tested class `T`.

The test class:

```
public class T_Test {
    @Tested T tested;

    D dependency;

    public void test() {
        dependency.doSomething();
        tested.testedMethod(dependency);
    }
}
```

I want the `dependency.doSomething()` will run the real code of this method, but that the abstract methods will be mocked.

1. If I run the test as is, I obviously get `NullPointerException` for using the uninitialized `dependency`.
2. If I add the `@Mocked` annotation to the `D dependency` line, all the methods in `D` are mocked, so `d.doSomething()` doesn't do what it's supposed to do.
3. If I keep the `@Mocked` annotation and also add an empty `NonStrictExpectations`  block at the beginning of the test method, in order to have partial mock, either like this:

   ```
   new NonStrictExpectations(D.class) {};
   ```

   or like this:

   ```
   new NonStrictExpectations(d) {};
   ```

   I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Already mocked: class D`.
4. If I keep the `NonStrictExpectations`  block and remove the `@Mocked` annotation, again I get `NullPointerException` for using the uninitialized `dependency`.

So how can I partially mock this dependency abstract class?

Comment: Can't you just assign the field with a concrete subclass of `D`?

Comment: I can, but I wondered what was the "right" way to do it.

I also found (after posting this question) that if I use `@Tested D`, although it's not the tested object, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `@Capturing` annotation on the dependency achieves this. No need to add an empty expectations block; only the abstract methods will be mocked.

```
public class T_Test {
    @Tested T tested;

    @Capturing D dependency;

    public void test() {
        dependency.doSomething();
        tested.testedMethod(dependency);
    }
}
```